# JavaScript select button and run it in a new tab and wait 8 seconds and then do the same process again

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do "`JavaScript` select button and run it in a new tab and wait 8 seconds and then do the same process again".

I'm a beginner user of JavaScript.

I have used I code, but it is still not working. I think it is wrong coded. See this. This is the first part of code.

```
setInterval(function () {
     document.getElementById("clk").click()window.open'_blank';
}, 8000);
```

This is the second part of the code:

```
var button = document.getElementById('clk');
setInterval(function(){
                 button.click(window.open('_blank'))
},8000)
```

**I repeat that what I want:**

Select "clk" id and open it in a new tab as well and wait 8 seconds and do the same process again.

I also want to clear to you that I don't know how to code. I'm in a learning period.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Muhammad. You might want to split your javascript code into a separate line per instruction, and use semi-colon `;` to indicate each instruction. Also, `window.open'_blank'` is a function, you forgot to include parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
<script>
var button = document.getElementById('clk');
button.click(
    setInterval(function () {
        window.open('_blank')
    }, 3000)
)
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy But Please how i can do a onclick open link in new tab but focus on present window

Answer (score 0):

You can set a new name for a window tab before opening.

In this example, the name is generated random from 1 to 10:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('clk');

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  setInterval(function () {
    var name = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    window.open('_blank', name);
  },8000)
});
```

We use `addEventListener` function to catch `click` event on the button.

Source:

- [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [JavaScript random() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp)